# XML Signing with SHA256ECDSA in jdk 7 - Is it possible?

Tags: java, xml-signature

I've been trying to sign an XML document using SHA256ECDSA, and I succeded using jdk 8. However, the same code is not working in jdk 7.
Can anybody tell me what I should change in my code to make it work in jdk7, or point me to an alternative solution (eg using other libs)?

Here's the code:

```
XMLSignatureFactory fac = XMLSignatureFactory.getInstance("DOM");

        SignedInfo si = null;
        try {
            Reference ref = fac.newReference("", fac.newDigestMethod(
                    DigestMethod.SHA256, null), Collections.singletonList(fac
                    .newTransform(Transform.ENVELOPED,
                            (TransformParameterSpec) null)), null, null);
            // Create the SignedInfo.
            si = fac.newSignedInfo(
                    fac.newCanonicalizationMethod(
                            CanonicalizationMethod.EXCLUSIVE,
                            (C14NMethodParameterSpec) null),
                    fac.newSignatureMethod(
                            "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#ecdsa-sha256",
                            null), Collections.singletonList(ref));

                            ...

        // Instantiate the document to be signed.
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
        Document doc = null;
        try {
            doc = dbf.newDocumentBuilder().parse(
                    new FileInputStream(PATH_TO_INPUT_XML));                            

                    ...

        // Create a DOMSignContext and specify the RSA PrivateKey and
        // location of the resulting XMLSignature's parent element.
        String keyPath = PATH_TO_PRIVATE_KEY;
        File privKeyFile = new File(keyPath);
        BufferedInputStream bis = null;
        byte[] privateKeyBytesDecoded = null;
        try {
            bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(privKeyFile));
            byte[] privKeyBytes = new byte[(int) privKeyFile.length()];
            bis.read(privKeyBytes);
            privateKeyBytesDecoded = Base64.decodeBase64(privKeyBytes);
            bis.close();

            ...

        KeyFactory keyFactory = null;
        PrivateKey privateKey = null;
        KeySpec ks = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(privateKeyBytesDecoded);
        try {
            keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("EC");
            privateKey = keyFactory.generatePrivate(ks);

            ...


        DOMSignContext dsc = new DOMSignContext(privateKey,
                doc.getDocumentElement());

        // Create the XMLSignature, but don't sign it yet.
        XMLSignature signature = fac.newXMLSignature(si, ki);                   

        // Marshal, generate, and sign the enveloped signature.
        try {
            signature.sign(dsc);
            ...
```

I get the following exception running this code in jkd 7:

> java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: unsupported algorithm
>       at org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMXMLSignatureFactory.newSignatureMethod(DOMXMLSignatureFactory.java:231)
>
> the line is:
>   fac.newSignatureMethod("http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#ecdsa-sha256",
>                               null), Collections.singletonList(ref));

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.
José.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Apache Santuario](http://santuario.apache.org/javaindex.html). The only line you would need to change would be the instantiation of the `XMLSignatureFactory`:

```
XMLSignatureFactory fac = XMLSignatureFactory.getInstance("DOM", new XMLDSigRI());
```

Where `XMLDSigRI` is `org.apache.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.XMLDSigRI`.